# How to add all binaries to bash tab completion for some command?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I've installed program `trickle` that allow to throttle the net for specified command like:

```
trickle -u10 -d10 <COMMAND>
```

How to add bash completion for all binaries to `trickle` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have, and load, the file `/etc/bash_complete` or an equivalent directory? It defines a bunch of completions and extension facilities beyond what's built into bash. If you have access to them, you can probably just use

```
complete -o filenames -F _command trickle
```

It will complete the first argument of trickle as a command, and will then try to apply appropriate completion rules for subsequent arguments. But it depends on the shell function `_command`, which is defined in the above file (in my Debian system, at least). YMMV on other Linux distributions, and the file doesn't seem to be present in Darwin (OS X 10.8).

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's an even simpler way to do this:

```
complete -c trickle
```

which will add completion of all available commands. If you wanted to do something fancy with its `-u` or `-d` options, there's useful information [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200507173259/http://www.debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2).

As an aside: Bash's `man` documentation for `complete` is pretty understandable but it's buried way down in the enormous `bash` manpage. The [HTML version](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) is much easier to get at.